# If today, display "today", once 1 day has passed display actual date in an efficient way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

What I want to do is whenever the user is viewing a `post`, if the current date is Today, then it should say `Today @ 3:35pm`, but if they are viewing that same post tomorrow it should say `Nov 8, 2014 @ 3:35pm`.

I know this is a simple `if` statement...but I am concerned that on every page load (especially for instance my `Post#Index` where 20 posts are shown at once) I have to be doing a `Date.today` if check.

Is there a more elegant way to do this that doesn't give me a performance hit?

In other words, I am trying to avoid a pseudo-N+1 problem with constantly hitting `Date.today` on every page load. i.e. is there a `counter_cache` solution for this problem?

Here is the current version:

```
<% if post.created_at == Date.today %>
    Today @ <%= post.created_at.strftime("%l:%M %P") %>
<% else %>
    <%= "#{post.created_at.strftime("%B %e, %Y")} @ #{post.created_at.strftime("%l:%M %P")}" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I wouldn't bother about `if` statement in this case. Much more important thing would be to cache these posts and here you'll get noticeable performance improvement.

Comment: Just do a simple fragment-cache? How hard is it to do? I thought about it, but I didn't want to get sucked into a complex setup and feel like I need to pull out my hair. Btw...can I cache these posts when I am using Disqus's comments on each post?

Comment: "Is there a more elegant way to do this that doesn't give me a performance hit?" - This gives you a performance hit? Really?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Hrmm...good point. I may be over-optimizing.

Comment: @marcamillion, anytime you consider what would be better within your view, you can do a benchmark. For views, e.g: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/performance_testing.html#view

Comment: Optimizing is good. Only you started from step 2. You need to go back to step 1: **profile the app and find *actual* slow parts**.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I am using mini-profiler the whole time, so I am monitoring load times and keeping an eye on everything. I was just thinking that intuitively, it felt like doing a call to `Date.today` was more heavy than say doing a counter_cache call...but I suspect I am mistaken, because I have since looked at the load times and now I feel silly :|

Comment: @marcamillion: IIRC, Donald Knuth said something along the lines of "programmers are exceptionally bad at intuitively detecting bottlenecks. In 90+% of cases, their guess is wrong"

Comment: Actually it's in Code Complete: http://books.google.ru/books?id=I-83BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA594&lpg=PA594&dq=why+programmers+are+bad+at+guessing+bottlenecks&source=bl&ots=4EQ2rLoAdq&sig=7Gvd0RwfwfYsyEyhRb6oveni6wE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=JSZeVMC7H4z2POargPgD&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=why%20programmers%20are%20bad%20at%20guessing%20bottlenecks&f=false

Comment: I feel ya...welp...this is awkward :} What shall we do about this question? Someone want to write an answer and I will accept it?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think performance is a real issue here. In any case you can implement that logic in your model

```
def display_created_at
  if created_at.today?
    "Today @ #{created_at.strftime('%l:%M %P')"
  else
    created_at.strftime("%B %e, %Y @ %l:%M %P")
  end
end
```

now you could use caching here, you could cache with one hour expiration, per record,

```
def cached_display_created_at
  Rails.cache.fetch(["post", id, "display_created_at"], expires_in: 1.hour) do
    display_created_at
  end
end
```

but (again) I do not think it will help performance wise.

Comment: Do I have to have any caching setup in advance? Because I haven't started caching anything. Or will this just work right out of the box?

Comment: I think it will even hurt performance. No way a request to memcached is going to be faster than local `Date.today`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I am not going to do this, but I like the idea.

Comment: @marcamillion: I know you won't. But someone else may be tempted. :)

Comment: @marcamillion out of the box, you just need to define a `cache_store` in the initializers. Check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#configuration .